# How to compare two dates (MonthName YearNumber) in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, date

This functionality is working fine in Chrome... But not IE or FF.

I am trying to validate two fields that take the value of MonthName YearNumber (see screenshot).

[image: form]

I am using `Date.parse()` to get miliseconds, then compare if `Start Date` <= `End Date`.

```
function IsStartEndDtError(StartDt, EndDt) {
    //convert dates to miliseconds to compare if one is greater than other
    var StartDtMili = Date.parse(StartDt);
    var EndDtMili = Date.parse(EndDt);

    if (StartDtMili <= EndDtMili) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What appears in Firebug:

[image: form2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the format your date is in isn't universally supported you can try a library like [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/):

```
Date.parse("November 2012")
// returns: Thu Nov 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

If you don't want another library you can manually replace the month names with numbers and create a new date string.

Ecmascript does not seem to support full month names, if you look at "Section 15.9.1.15 Date Time String Format" in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

In Firefox:

```
new Date("November 2012")
// Invalid Date
new Date("2012-11")
// Thu Nov 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

The second date format should be standardized across browsers, the first isn't.

Answer (score 1):

`11 1999`, `November 1999` are not parsable formats. You either need to use a date library that is more flexible with its input formats, or process your input and identify the parts in it:

```
function IsStartEndDtError(StartDt, EndDt) {

    var months = {
        January: 0,
        February: 1,
        ...
    };

    //convert dates to miliseconds to compare if one is greater than other

    var StartDtMili = (new Date(StartDt.split(" ")[1], month[StartDt.split(" ")[0]])).getTime();
    var EndDtMili = (new Date(EndDt.split(" ")[1], month[EndDt.split(" ")[0]])).getTime();


    if (StartDtMili <= EndDtMili) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get NaN using this method in IE and FF.  http://i46.tinypic.com/1h2mqh.gif  

Ah, you made edits!  I'll try your new code and see... Thanks.

Comment: @KKKKKKKK That is because you are using `November 1999`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: months are zero based in `Date` object